How many intersections are there for two confocal parabolas with their axis perpendicular to each other?
I assumed it to be 4 but I was wrong. I tried to write the equations of the parabolas by making them in standard form through origin shifting and rotation of axis and also wrote coordinates in parametric form but had no results?
So how many intersection can two confocal parabolas have when their axis are perpendicular to each other?

Take the focus to be the origin. Since the axes are perpendicular the directrices are also. The four points are then with mutiplicities over ${\Bbb C}$ given by $$\langle (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)-(ax+by+c_1)^2, (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)-(-bx+ay+c_2)^2\rangle$$ In lex order we get the discriminant of the two factors of the degree four expression of the $y$-coordinates to be $8c_1c_2(a-b)^2(a^2+b^2)^4$ and $-8c_1c_2(a+b)^2(a^2+b^2)^4$ which are of opposite sign meaning two of the intersection points have imaginary $y$-coordinates.

There's a simple geometric argument for why it's not 4, but at most 2 points. While intuitively, I can see how it must be exactly 2 and not less, I don't have a clear geometric argument for that yet.
Put the focus at the origin $O$, set one directrix horizontally below the origin, at $y=-h$ (that parabola's axis is vertical) and one directrix vertically left of the origin, at $x=-v$ (that parabola points right).
A parabola is the locus of points equidistant from the focus and directrix. A point of intersection of the two parabolas is at some distance $d$ from $O$. Therefore, it is at distance $d$ from either directrix. Since a parabola is only on one side of its directrix, the point must be at $(-h+d, -v+d)$.
In other words, all points of intersection of the two parabolas lie must lie on a 45 degree line through $(-h,-v)$. That line intersects either parabola at most twice -- thus, there are at most two intersection points.
